# Should we use plural or singular for a fraction of a mile?

Tags: grammatical-number, numbers, measuring-units, fractions

I have seen people say both 0.25 mile and 0.25 miles. Should we use plural or singular for a fraction of a mile?

Comment: Is the question about what is correct to write, or what you should say?

Comment: In Irish, plurals are not used directly after a number. This has affected Hiberno-English, and "five mile" would not be an uncommon phrasing here. Elsewhere, @ShreevatsaR's answer applies.

Comment: @TRiG: Make that an answer.

Comment: Maybe change 'fractions' for 'decimals' in the title? (As the answer is different for fractions!)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

0.25 miles.

The rule I follow is that you use the singular only when talking of exactly **one mile**. You'd also say half **a mile**, quarter of **a mile**, etc., but in these cases it's as though you're still talking of "a mile" first, and then taking half or quarter of it.

Let me say something further, with the caveat that it may be my own idiosyncratic usage: use the singular only when talking of the natural number 1, that is, when you're essentially "counting" miles and there's a single one of them. Use the plural in all other cases, even for the real number 1.0: just like "0.9 miles" or "1.1 miles", also say "1.0 miles" (but "1 mile").

[Mathematically, natural numbers ("counting numbers") are a subset of real numbers, but more properly what we have is an [inclusion map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion_map), so it *does* make sense to distinguish between 1 and 1.0, actually. And the distinction between natural numbers and real numbers does have applications elsewhere in English: consider "fewer than" versus "less than". You'd say "fewer than five items" but "less than 5.0 inches", since a length doesn't have to be an integer number of inches, you're not counting but assigning a real value.]

Another aside: the SI standard for symbols is to use the same symbol for singular or plural, so you'd write "2 km" even if you were reading it as "2 kilometres". Of course, since you're using miles, you probably don't care about this. :-)

Comment: Your way of doing "1.0 miles" is how I would say it too.  Cool observation.

Comment: If you choose to abbreviate Imperial units, you would also say 2 mi, 1 mi, 3.14159 mi, etc.

Comment: And of course, since zero is not the same as one, this means that a plural is always used when there are none - "0 miles", "no miles", "no avocados" and so on.

Comment: Actually this doesn't just have to do with natural numbers vs. real numbers -- it has more to do with the word "one".  For example, "I have three minus two cars" uses the plural, despite the number of cars being the natural number one. (You can't argue that this has to be interpreted as short for "three cars minus two cars", because that expansion doesn't work for "three times two cars" or "six divided by two cars".) See extensive discussion in [a related question about -1](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9735/is-1-singular-or-plural).

Comment: Interesting, never heard of this "inclusion map" thing

Comment: @Kosmonaut Sorry to bump an old post, but to your comment, apparently that is the defined way in the CMOS: https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/Numbers/faq0058.html

Comment: There is something weird though about 1.1 with respect to miles.  I have a place in my typical drive where Siri says, "In 1.1 miles, take the exit" and several people who have ridden with me have said, "that's strange, she just said it wrong" and felt that 1.1 mile was better.  But this violates every rule I've ever learned.

Answer (score 10):

Depends how you say it. You'd say "nought point two five miles" (plural) but "a quarter of a mile" (singular)

Comment: Well, *some* people would say "zero point two five", or "oh point two five", or just "point two five". Not too many noughts in the U.S.

Comment: That's because when you're talking about "a quarter mile" you are essentially saying "1" unit measured in "quarter-miles". Your unit of measure is different. There's still one of them.

Answer (score 3):

I'd leave it singular unless talking about a range such as "0.25 - 2 miles". In a table, for example, the heading would be the same regardless of the units. You can always abbreviate as "mi" and avoid the issue.

[Simon's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2139/0-25-mile-or-0-25-miles/2140#2140) is also good. Also note that it's actually more awkward to say 0.25 mile than "point two five of a mile".

Comment: I don't think this is helpful, abbreviating or table headings aren't really relevant to the point.

Comment: No context was given, so we really don't know what will or won't be helpful.

Comment: true, there is not much context, but without context the most general case would apply, and thus abbreviations or table headings don't seem relevant.

Comment: The same applies to "1 to 2 miles" so it isn't decimal specific

Comment: "Point two five of a mile" seems a bit more awkward than "Point two five miles"

Answer (score 3):

For reasons I'm not too sure about, we usually say "0.25 miles" rather than "0.25 mile". If you Google for both terms, there are about 700,000 "0.25 miles" but less than 100,000 "0.25 mile", and the first few hits for "0.25 mile" give things like "0.25 mile swim" or "0.25 mile wireless setup", where the "mile" is forced to singular anyway.

Comment: This is because 0.25 is plural. It's 25 units. The unit is hundredths of 1 mile. However, when used in context of a 0.25 mile swim ( or a 7 mile swim ) you're talking about the entire length as a unit of 1 again. a single swim which is 0.25 miles.

Answer (score 2):

If we followed the definition of "plural", the correct usage would be:

0.25 mile

0.5 mile

0.9 mile

1.0 mile

1.3 mile (or 1.3 miles, according to Wiktionary note below)

2.0 miles

2.2 miles
..

As the definition is:

> **Plural:** of, relating to, or constituting a
>   class of grammatical forms usually
>   used to denote more than one or in
>   some languages more than two

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/plural

However, as Shinto pointed out in his answer here, people usually use the plural form for 0.25.

Here is [an interesting note from the Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pl.) about the usage of plural for fractions (and decimals) in general:

> While the plural form generally refers
>   to two or more persons or things, that
>   is not always the case. The plural
>   form is often used for zero persons or
>   things, **for fractional things in a
>   quantity greater than one**, and for
>   people or things when the quantity is
>   unknown.

This does support the usage of plural for 0.25 though, since it is less than one. But if that is how people use it, we definitely can't say that it is incorrect.

Comment: really, though, in English plural is used for any number that is not 1. 1 mile, 1 1/4 miles, 1.3 miles, 1.00000001 miles, 0.9 miles, 0 miles, etc.

Comment: Even 1.00 miles isn't necessarily one mile; it could be anywhere from about 0.995 to 1.005, so I'd suggest the plural there too.

Comment: 0.25 is more than one hundredth. It's 25 hundredths. 25 > 1... so it's plural. 0 is an odd one, mind you... but let's be honest. 0 doesn't fit in a lot of places... as it's kind of a concept unto itself. 1.0 miles though... i have no answer for that one.

Answer (score 2):

.25 miles or a quarter of a mile.

Answer (score 2):

It's really not complicated or confusing if you think of it in terms of being a fraction.

Essentially, as soon as you go into decimal, you're changing units into partial units.

**0.25 would actually be 25 units of "hundredth-miles"**