# Plural for decimals?

Tags: grammatical-number

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [0.25 mile or 0.25 miles?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2139/0-25-mile-or-0-25-miles)

When writing out a quantity and then a noun what is the correct form for decimals?

```
1 day
2 days
.5 days?
```

It seems that if you were to say "half day" then the singular is reasonable but if you were to day "point five days" that also seems correct.

Answer (score 3):

You are right, one would say 'half a day'. One would also say '.5 of a day', but '.5 days'. The difference is that in the '.5 days', the verb *day* is described by a number other than *one*, in the other example, you've effectively got 'one .5 of a day', which means that *day* is qualified it with *one*, thus making it is singular.