# Do you add 's' after countable nouns following numbers other than 1?

Tags: countable-nouns

For countable nouns you add 's' for non single quantity
e.g. 1 hour, 2 hours, -1 degree, -2 degrees

What about 0 hour(s)? 0.5 hour(s)? 1.5 hour(s)?

Comment: See this for a detailed answer: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/69162/are-these-plural-or-singular

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the number of units is not equal to one, use the plural noun.

Comment: Care to add reference? As 0 hours doesnt sound right to me at all.

Comment: Sorry, just experience.  But if it helps, part of that experience is dealing with dynamic text in programming- e.g. `Your search returned $number $results.` and the standard output is singular `$results` for `$number = 1` and plural `$results` for everything else, including zero. ps `$word` means a variable.

Comment: Ok, thats usual practice then, thank you. Although I'm still hoping to see the reference to a grammar rule.

Comment: That is the English grammar rule. Regular nouns get -s on the end for the plural form: noun/nouns. Nouns ending in -y change to -ies: fly/flies. But some nouns are irregular: mouse/mice, moose/moose, goose/geese. You just have to memorize the plural forms.

Comment: Figured it makes more sense to simply comment: 0 + (any noun) always results in the noun being treated plural. 0 hours is correct. Just run a few examples through your head. I'll give you a head start: 0 dogs, 0 chairs, 0 mice, 0 cars, 0 blankets.. it's just always pluralized. I don't know if there is a more elaborate explanation to it than what I just told you though.