# Why do we say "0.5 days" but "1 day" when both refer to a singular day?

Tags: grammatical-number

Unless I'm just using bad grammar I guess, it feels more natural when talking to someone to say "zero point five days" when referring to `0.5 days`; conversely, it sounds more natural to say "one day" when referring to `1 day`.

A similar question might be relevant: Why do we say "half a day" when describing the value, but "zero point five days" when being numerically specific?

Comment: See *[Should we use plural or singular for a fraction of a mile?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2139)* and  *[Are these plural or singular?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/69162)* for usage notes.

Comment: “0.5 days” does not refer to a singular day ... it’s less than that

Comment: There are lots of good questions to close this as a duplicate of. I am going with one that's probably not the most obvious at first sight, because it's got [this canonical answer by a linguist](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/9796/300). "The only number that is singular is one." 0.5 is not singular because it is not one. And "half a day" is a red herring entirely. I am not really sure where you're even going with that one.

Answer (score 1):

It might have to do with the fact that plural units are a numeric consensus where the singular is the exception. That's largely related to the fact that the idea of *one-or-many* existed before the (widespread) concept of Math (and mathematical subdivisions of an item) and the concept of zero in many cultures and languages. Relative subdivisions of a whole were largely considered independent units, especially in (but, again, not limited to) English. Consider and compare *0.5 days* to *half day*, or *0.25 days* to a *quarter day*.

I personally find it odd to use the singular noun on something that is not a singular unit, even if it is part of a singular unit. However, such examples do exist, and people would be prone to verbally append *of a* between the numeric and the unit, such as *0.5 (of a) day* whenever encountered with a written *0.5 day*.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer? English is a bit weird and there's no real consensus on the matter.

According to the AP Style Guide, when the decimal is 1 or less, the singular should be used. The Chicago Manual of Style disagrees, and uses the plural.

As far as "why isn't there consistency?" goes, I don't know that you'll find a real answer outside of the fact that language evolves and sometimes it's a messy process without much logic behind it.