# Is it two-third or two-thirds?

Tags: nouns, syntactic-analysis

Is it two-third or two-thirds? If both are correct, how does their usage differ?

Comment: Any fractional number (_half, third, fourth, ..._) is singular following _one_, and plural following any other cardinal number.

Comment: Referring to the comment from @JohnLawler, note that Americans tend to use *a fourth*, whereas Brits use *a quarter*. I think it would be **extremely rare** to hear a Brit using *a fourth*.

Comment: _Quarter_ is used by itself to mean 1/4 in the US (_only a quarter tank left_), but it's also the name of the US 25¢ coin. 3/4 can be either _three-fourths_ or _three quarters_. _Fourth_ generally requires _of_ plus an article, while singular _quarter_ doesn't: _a/one fourth of a mile, a/one quarter (of a) mile, three-fourths of a mile,_ but _three quarters of a mile_.

Comment: @JohnLawler Interesting. I think we (Brits) would normally *say* "a quarter *of a* mile", altho' we may *write* "a quarter mile". I don't think we would normally say or write "*one* quarter (of a) mile".

Comment: @Mari-LouA I don't think this is a duplicate of the linked question: that one is discussing using digits or words, whereas this one is asking about using the plural forms.

Comment: @TrevorD yes, you're right. My bad. I thought I had seen the answer to the OP's question, something about "three-fourths"?? So maybe "two-thirds"? I have always been weak on maths, my eyes glaze over whenever I meet this type of question. Wait! The OP himself supplies the answer in his first line.

Comment: quote: I know in more formal writing, spelling out fractions is preferred (e.g. two-thirds), and in math no suffix is used, but I .....

Comment: What about this one: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42370/is-two-thirds-plural?lq=1 ??

Comment: @TrevorD  On the other hand, this OP might be a spammer. He's never replied... to anyone.

Comment: Who cares? Pleasing OPs is not our reason for existing. This is a pretty interesting discussion.

Comment: @JohnLawler I was musing further on this. I would normally say (and I think I'm typical of Brits in this respect) "half ***a*** mile" but "***a*** quarter ***of a*** mile" or "three-quarters ***of a*** mile". I think I'd use the latter formats for all fractions except 'half'.

Answer (score 18):

A third, like any other unit of measurement, is dependent on the number of units described. For example, we describe 'one apple' and 'two apples'. The same goes for fractional units. 'one third' is simply a single unit of 'third'. Two or more and we use 'thirds'; hence, 'two-thirds' is the correct usage.

Answer (score 0):

Quite correct, but it should be noted that the hyphen is not always used:

The motion was carried by a two-thirds majority.

At least two thirds of business research and development expenditure was found to be wasted.

depending on whether the phrase is used as an attributive adjective (first case) or simply as an adective + noun combination (second).

Comment: In the second case, whether or not to use a hyphen can be a matter of style. For example, The Guardian's house style is to always use a hyphen.

Comment: I don't agree that it's a style issue. Most authoritative references on the English language consider that when used as a non-attributive adjective, the hyphen should not be present (Oxford Dictionary, Chicago Manual of Style, and more). Since when has the Guardian been such a reference? "One half of the beach was covered in oil." Would it be OK to use a hyphen here?

Answer (score 0):

Any fractional number (*half, third, fourth*, ...) is singular following *one*, and plural following any other cardinal number. –  John Lawler