# Using degrees for directions: should it be singular or plural

Tags: grammatical-number

I am confused whether to use singular or plural for "degree" used in directions/bearings. Is it grammatically correct to write "1 degree East of South", and "0.23 degrees West of South"?

Comment: With anything other than 1, use plural agreement.

Comment: By "1" you mean to include 1.0? I have read in another site that degrees should be ALWAYS plural: https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/0-175-meters-or-0-175-meter.69250/

Comment: Interesting point. Yes, 1.0 sounds better with plural agreement (and not just with compass directions). I suppose anything other than literally "1" should have plural agreement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally with any units we use the singular with 1 and the plural with anything else.

Some cases where there is disagreement are:

1. -1. Some take this as a case of *one* and some as a case of *not-one* and pluralise accordingly. (see [Is -1 followed by a singular or plural noun?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9735/is-1-followed-by-a-singular-or-plural-noun))
2. 1.0 or other cases of 1 with greater precision than integer. Again, some take this as a case of *one* but generally it's taken as a case of *not-one* (see [Is 1.0 singular or plural?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44489/is-1-0-singular-or-plural))
3. Adjectival use. This doesn't so much happen with directions but does with other uses of degrees. An angle of 30 degrees is a 30-degree angle. This is an extension of how attributive uses of nouns are singular. (Even in always-plural cases; a press for trousers is a trouser-press, a sharpener for scissor-sharpener, most book shops have more than one book). (This seems to be why the EU advised at one point that the plural for *Euro* in English should be *Euros* despite the general advice being to follow the normal pluralisation rules of the language in question; someone got thrown by such expressions as "ten-pound note").