# Should one use singular or plural form when the number is equivalent to one or negative one?

Tags: grammatical-number, mathematics

I understand that for a countable noun, one is supposed to use the singular form if and only if the number is equal to one or negative one; for example:

- one degree
- negative one degree
- 0.75 degree**s**

Now my question is, what if the number is not expressed explicitly as one or negative one, but is essentially equal to one? For example, which of the following is correct:

- 1.0 degree or 1.0 degrees?
- negative four over four degree or negative four over four degrees?

**Edit**: I just realised that for the difference between 1.0 degrees and 1.0 degree, it has been answered [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44489/is-1-0-singular-or-plural?rq=1). However, the question about negative four over four degree or negative four over four degrees remains unclear to me.

Comment: Also @JJJ The title and body of the Q do not seem to agree.

Comment: @Kris the answers certainly do, the difference seems to be between countable / uncountable things.  Take as an example [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/9764/71848). [This answers also has some relevant considerations](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/10471/71848)