# Is it hour or hours when used in a phrase?

Tags: phrases, grammatical-number

I recently joined a company as a trainee and we have to skype our priorities or task that we are going to do on that day.

For example, people write priorities like this:

**1. HTML/CSS training - [0.5 hours].**

**2. PHP training - [9 hours].**

Now I do know about quasi possessive but this doesn't sound like a quasi possessive. I want to know whether it should be 9 hour or 9 hours? Maybe it might be 9 hours because it's more than 1 but writing 0.5 hours seems a bit confusing. Please let me know what's the correct usage. Thank you.

Comment: It's plural in all cases except for 1 hour.

Comment: The reason 0.5 hours seems odd is because you're used to say "half an hour" (or similar) - but a half is not a single :)

Comment: Whether you use hour or hours would seem of minor consideration compared to your use of *gonna* and *wanna*. Don't you get marked down professionally for doing that?

Comment: If "0.5 hours" seems confusing, that only means you're a non-native speaker who hasn't quite got used to the way English runs things. "0.5 hours" is perfectly fine English; "0.5 hour" would be ungrammatical nonsense. See the [linked question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2139/should-we-use-plural-or-singular-for-a-fraction-of-a-mile) for an excellent in-depth answer. Meanwhile Jim right here provides a nice executive summary: one is singular. Everything else is not singular. Simple as that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually a decimal portion of an hour is followed by "hours". Like 2.5 hours, 1.5 hours, 0.5 hours etc. However normally we say *half an hour* or *thirty minutes* not 0.5 hrs.