# Is "89.9%" singular or plural?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, percentages

I’m writing a dissertation on network security. I’m unsure which of the following to use:

1. ...89.9%, which **is** 57 million users.
2. ...89.9%, which **are** 57 million users.

Technically it should be *are* because it refers to a plural amount of people, but it doesn’t sound right to me considering that *57 million* is in a sense one group.

Comment: Realted (possible dupe):[plural or singular for fractions of a mile?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/2139/8019)

Answer (score 3):

The correct term is "which is". You are referring to the percentage (singular), so "89.9%, which is 57 million users" is the proper grammatical usage.

Comment: you are not referring to the percentage but to 89.9 percent (plural)