# Should you say "0.9 second" rather than "0.9 seconds"?

Tags: grammatical-number, science, measuring-units

When looking through the [National Physical Laboratory's SI unit conventions](http://www.npl.co.uk/reference/measurement-units/si-conventions/), I have found a strange clause in their list:

> - For unit values more than 1 or less than -1 the plural of the unit is used and a singular unit is used for values between 1 and -1.

If you follow this rule through, you would condemn the following usage:

> UTC is kept always within **0.9 seconds** of UT1 by the insertion of extra seconds as necessary (known as positive leap seconds). It could happen that seconds would need to be removed (negative leap seconds), but so far all leap seconds have been positive.

This quote has come directly from [an article by the NPL about leap seconds](http://www.npl.co.uk/educate-explore/what-is-time/the-leap-second) showing that even *they* don't follow their own rules.
[Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=0.1+second%2C0.1+seconds%2C0.2+second%2C0.2+seconds&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C0.1%20second%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C0.1%20seconds%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C0.2%20second%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C0.2%20seconds%3B%2Cc0) contains several false positives but places "0.1 second" above "0.1 seconds" but "0.2 second(s)" is the other way round.

Is this rule kept to?
Does it have any bearing in scientific English?

Comment: Just to confuse matters a little more, some people would say *0.9 of a second*! *Jones was 0.9 of second faster than Smith, in the 400 metres*.

Comment: The problem disappears if *seconds* in that quote is not referring to the SI unit -- perhaps it's referring to a CGS second. Certainly the [usual usage](/q/2139) is for the singular noun to be used only for **exactly one** of them.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Yes, naturally I would only use the grammatical singular for -1 or 1 unit. However, I would say 1.0 (one point zero) unit**s**.

Comment: @WS2 Thinking about it, I  would usually only say *of a second* if I omitted the zero before the point. I.e. *Jones was **point nine** of a second* rather than  *Jones was **zero point nine** of a second*. Would you also follow that rule?

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey You may well be right as far as most people are concerned. However, speaking personally, I think I might also say *0.9 of a second faster*.

Comment: @WS2 Perhaps it's more of a generational thing

Comment: This might be useful: [Should we use plural or singular for a fraction of a mile?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2139/should-we-use-plural-or-singular-for-a-fraction-of-a-mile)

Answer (score 5):

At the computer magazines where I worked for many years, we had a strict house rule to identify measurements of less than one with a singular unit of measure. For example, we would say

> ¾ inch *or* 0.75 inch

not

> ¾ inches *or* 0.75 inches

This style decision required endless enforcement because many of our writers habitually used plural units of measure with measurements of less than one.

One style guide that shares our old house style preference is *Words into Type*, third edition (1974), which offers this advice:

> **Decimals.** For quantities of less than one, a zero should be set before the decimal point except for quantities that never exceed one. Also, when units are not abbreviated the singular is used for quantities of one or less.  ... [Relevant examples:] *0.32 second*, *0.75 grain*

*The Chicago Manual of Style*, sixteenth edition (2010) evades this question almost completely. But to the extent that it has anything useful to say on the subject, it tends to contradict *Words into Type*. Here is the most direct remark it makes on the subject:

> **10.68 *Plural form for abbreviations of US measure.*** Abbreviations of US units of measure, like their scientific counterpart, are identical in the singular and plural. ... Note that the unit of measure in such expressions as 0.5 yd. and 1.5 yd. is generally pronounced as if it were plural (i.e., point five yards; one point five yards).

This last statement seems to suggest that *Chicago* endorses writing out *0.5 yd.* as *0.5 yards* rather than as *0.5 yard*—although it never explicitly says so. It's a very odd treatment, when you think about it: *Chicago* offers its opinion about how *0.5 yd.* "is generally pronounced" by U.S. English speakers but never specifies whether U.S. writers should spell out *0.5 yd.* as *0.5 yard* or as *0.5 yards*. From this episode, you might think that the book was called *The Chicago Manual of Pronunciation Style*.

*The Oxford Guide to Style* (2002) sides with *Words into Type* on this matter:

> **7.2 Units** ... Elsewhere [that is, aside from instances where units help form compound adjectives, as in "a two-mile walk"], units are pluralized as necessary, but not if the quantity or number is less than one: *two kilos*, *three miles*, *0.568 litre*, *half a pint*.

If I recall correctly, part of the rationale (at the computer magazines where I worked) for using singular units of measure for quantities less than one was that it helped avoid misreadings of, for example, ".8 pound[s]" as "8 pounds." (That is also a sound reason for including the zero before the decimal point, by the way.) But more than anything else, I think, we were swayed by the idea that a number consisting of a fraction less than one would certainly be attached to a singular unit (for example, ⅝ inch), so it wouldn't make sense to treat the exact decimal equivalent of ⅝ (0.625) as taking a plural unit of measure (inches) instead of a singular one (inch). But obviously, reasonable (and unreasonable) people differ on this question.

Answer (score 2):

I think the rule as written differs significantly from the common usage.

It is normal to use the plural "seconds" in all cases.

As @WS2 identified, the phrase "of a second" is also fairly common when refering to a fraction of a second less than 1.