# Mentioning a physical unit after a series of values

Tags: measuring-units, academic-writing

I have problem deciding which one of the following sentences is correct considering the usage of second(s):

> Computation times of the proposed algorithms are in the orders of 10^-3 and 10^-4 seconds, which are small compared to the sampling times of 0.1 and 1 second.

> Computation times of the proposed algorithms are in the orders of 10^-3 seconds and 10^-4 seconds, which are small compared to the sampling times of 0.1 second and 1 second.

Both look strange to me regarding the usage of second(s). The first one looks redundant, and the second one seems inadequate.

Comment: 'Serie' is obsloete in English. The plural is invariant: 1 series, 2 series, a million series.

Comment: Thanks Edwin! I corrected it.

Comment: I would take a look at print examples in your field. You might find s or sec is more common, and it saves space. I see no reason to write it out in full when it's being used as a unit after a number.

Comment: I see your point. I think I will go with sec. Thank you!

Comment: _0.1 second**s** and 1 second_ ...or... _0.1 and 1 second**s**_. Best:  _0.1 and 1 **.0** second**s**_.

Comment: And it isn't *in the orders of*, it's *on the order of*. Don't pluralize *order* here, it is an adverbial. You can add a *respectively* if it feels better to you. It's a different kind of order from *on the orders of Captain Ahab*

Comment: Related: [CMoS FAQ](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/Numbers/faq0058.html), and also [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9735/is-1-followed-by-a-singular-or-plural-noun), [this one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2139/should-we-use-plural-or-singular-for-a-fraction-of-a-mile), and [this one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/365841/should-you-say-0-9-second-rather-than-0-9-seconds).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason people use the plural for both values above 1 (as you would expect)and below 1. e.g.

0.5 seconds
1 second
2 seconds

and people tend to say "1.0 seconds"

"0.1 and 1 second" is a problem. You don't really want to use "0.1 seconds and 1 second" because, whilst not incorrect, is sounds verbose. And "0.1 and 1 second" sounds wrong.

Tinfoil Hat's solution is to say "0.1 and 1.0 seconds" which is perfect English but I think may not be scientifically correct. The presence and number of decimal places is typically used to indicate precision so 1 second and 1.0 seconds are not necessarily the same in precise meaning, if you see what I mean.

Of course the problem disappears if you use the ordinary English abbreviation "sec." or the standard SI Unit abbreviation of "s".