# Use of singular or plural form for decimal money units

Tags: grammatical-number, measuring-units, money

According to these following articles:

- [**The Chicago Manual of Style Online:**
  Numbers: Q. When referring to decimals from zero to one, are they singular or plural?](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/Numbers/faq0058.html)
- [**Stack Exchage (English Language & Usage):**
  Should we use plural or singular for a fraction of a mile?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2139/should-we-use-plural-or-singular-for-a-fraction-of-a-mile)
- [**WordReference Forums:**
  fraction/ decimal number + noun (singular or plural?)](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/fraction-decimal-number-noun-singular-or-plural.2407046/)

**all decimals use plural form for its units regardless of the integer part being zero, one, two, etc.**

> i.e.: 0.8 mile**s**, 1.8 mile**s**, 2.8 mile**s**, etc.

Let us now assume we have **"$1.01"**, a decimal with money units. Although the written form contains decimal point, which is the correct way of saying it **<A>** or **<B>**?
(Note: what is in between "[ ]" below is optional, you can say it with or without it)

> - **<A>**: one dollar   [and] one [cent]      =   both singular form of units
> - **<B>**: one dollar**s** [and] one [cent**s**]    =   both plural form of units

I believe for **"$1.01"**, although it is in decimal format, **<A>** is the correct one. This is because the decimal point act rather like a delimiter between 2 units (dollar and cent) with 1 as a value ... rather than as a decimal point with 1 unit (dollar).

Out of curiosity, if someone said **"$1.01"** in decimal format with 1 unit (dollar), then is the following the only valid way of saying it (with plural form of the units).

> - one point zero one dollar**s**

Comment: This isn't really on-topic; _one point zero one dollars_ is correct but almost never encountered outside an explanatory mathematics lesson (where it would be stressed that though 'one point zero/o one dollars/pounds' follow the same form as 'one point zero one miles', 'one point zero one degrees', 'one point zero one square feet' etc, no one ever uses this for money.

Comment: In fact, this often causes confusion among children: though 'one dollar 33 [cents]' are correct, 'one point thirty-three miles' is an incorrect way to express 1·33 mile/s. As does the fact that rules in science are usually that the singular form of units be used.

Comment: Thanks [Edwin Ashworth](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/21655/edwin-ashworth). I see. It seems that it is different for which community you belong to. Assuming we are in the community of **The Chicago Manual of Style**  (publishing ???), I wonder which will be correct above ... **<A>** or **<B>**?

Comment: The plural form _dollars_ is with decimal **notation** not currency. B is incorrect, outlandish, in any register / style guide.